# mod rewrite is not working in my template

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have a htm/css template with what appears to be mod_rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} gallery\_remote2\.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/main\.php$
    RewriteRule .   -   [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /d/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/([^/?]+)(\?.|\ .)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/main\.php$
    RewriteRule .   /main.php?g2_view=core.DownloadItem&g2_itemId=%1&g2_serialNumber=%2&g2_fileName=%3   [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /v/([^?]+)(\?.|\ .)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/main\.php$

    RewriteRule .   /main.php?g2_path=%1   [QSA,L]

    RewriteRule ^presentation/([0-9]+)$ /presentation.php?id=$1


    ErrorDocument 404 /notavailable.php
</IfModule>
```

This part is mine: `RewriteRule ^presentation/([0-9]+)$ /presentation.php?id=$1`

the url I have now is www.domain.com/presentation.php?id=1

and I want www.domain.com/presentation/1/

Mine is not working, and was wondering if my rules are wrong or conflictinf with the ones already there.

EDIT:

Ok I got this to work: `RewriteRule ^presentation/([0-9]+)$ /presentation.php?id=$1 [L]`

so www.domain.com/presentation/2   I want a rule with either no slash or slash at the end... but we cant deal with that later..

Now the problem is that although the id is being retrieved, the website acts as if there is a presentation directory, therefore all the relative paths like including the header don't work. Actually, I think the css links are broken.

Comment: mod_rewrite does not change the URLs displayed in the browser. You have to adapt your application to output the nicer URLs. The RewriteRules only change the webserver-internal dispatching. -- If your rule is not working, move it higher up before the other rules.

Comment: I know it wont change www.domain.com/presentation.php?id=1 to www.domain.com/presentation/1/  but typing www.domain.com/presentation/1/ should direct it to the right page?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if you do want URL in the browser to change then have define your rewrite rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^presentation/([0-9]+)$ /presentation.php?id=$1 [R=301,L]
```

That simply means return HTTP status 301 to the browser with the new URL.

And that way your problem of browser not finding image, css, image etc using relative paths will also be taken care of.